# Translate Flow Label

Tags: visual-workflow, action, actions-and-recommendations

we are using Flows in the Actions & Recommendation Section on the Leads Object. My problem is: We can translate the most content of this flow, but NOT the label. But this label is displayed in the Actions & Reommendation Section.

Is there any option, to translate the Flow Label here? I'm really open for any idea or suggestion. Or is there maybe a workaround?

Hope there are any ideas.

Best Hannes